# Sharing PC's screen with other users - RDC

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

Due to the pandemic, we are working from home, and I'm connecting to my work PC remotely using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection (RDC). How can I share my work PC's screen with my colleagues?

I want to show them how to do a specific task that I'm familiar with. It would be easier if I could share the screen with them.

I could do this using tools like Skype. But it would be easier if I could do this using RDC.

Comment: hi, according to my research, it seems cannot be achieved in RDP, but With Windows Desktop Sharing, a local desktop can be transmitted over an RDP connection without creating an additional session. Please refer to:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/rdp/rdp-portal